# Adding Custom UIScreen to CarPlay

Tags: ios, swift, carplay

I am working on a CarPlay App ( with its own UI to be shown in carPly ). But, when I test it in simulator, I am seeing the same issue as the below question : 
[Adding a CarPlay UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45301362/adding-a-carplay-ui/48407468?noredirect=1#comment83803970_48407468)

I am not even getting UIScreenDidConnect notification when CarPlay is connected.
I even tried checking the UISCreen.screens.count value. It is also showing as 1 (main iPhone screen).

How can I render my screen to CarPlay UI ? Why am I not getting the UIScreen events  ?

Comment: Did you ever figure anything out?

Answer (score 2):

As of iOS 12, custom UI is only available for CarPlay navigation apps. There is no *general* CarPlay app development yet for the public.